# When does K-Means give High Quality Clusters?

Tags: clustering, k-means

It's well known k-means algorithm is effective when the clusters are spherically or elliptically distributed. This data assumption is not true in many real world data examples. Are there real-world settings where this assumption *is* approximately true?

As far as I can tell, the primary advantage of k-means is speed, at the expense of cluster quality. However, if I am looking for high quality clusters, are there datasets/settings in which k-means delivers?

Comment: k-means is not very good for elliptic, elongated clusters

Comment: I was using https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/clustering/algorithm/advantages-disadvantages as a reference for k-means and elliptical data, although perhaps I should have clarified that k-means could be tweaked to work on elliiptical data sets (rather than working straight out of the box). Thanks for the comment!